# Langrange multiplier, confusion at setting up the problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

**Question**

Find the rectangular box with the largest volume that fits inside the ellipsoid x2/a2 + y2/b2 + z2/c2 = 1, given that it sides are parallel to the axes

**Solution**

Clearly the box will have the greatest volume if each of its corners touch the ellipse. Let one of the corners (x, y, z) be in the positive octant, then the box has corners (±x, ±y, ±z) and its volume is V = 8xyz.

I don't understand how they volume is equivalent to 8xyz, why isn't $V=xyz$?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of sides are $x-(-x)=2x,y-(-y)=2y$ and $z-(-z)=2z$ so the volume is $$V=2^3xyz=8xyz.$$

Comment: How did you calculate the length of sides? I can't seem to intuitively understand that bit

Comment: When you have a segment $[a,b],$ the length is given by $|b-a|.$ Here, the segments that define your box are given in your solution by $[-x,x],[-y,y]$ and $[-z,z],$ and I just compute $|x-(-x)|=2x$ ($x>0$), etc.

Comment: I understand that however I don't get where my solution obtained the segments from

Comment: It comes just from a choice of model : the question ask you to consider a box with sides parallel  to the axes, so you could have put a corner of your box at the origin and chose points $x,y$ and $z$ on each axes, which gives you your initial formula of volume $V=xyz$ or following the solution which centered the box at the origin (you can do a draw to realize it) ; you can of course chose an other representation but these two seems to be the easiest to me.